# Why cant we create the object of InetAddress class using new keyword

Tags: java

I check the code `InetAddress` class file in my java development package and I see the following lines.

Line no : 302 - 308

```
/**
     * Constructor for the Socket.accept() method.
     * This creates an empty InetAddress, which is filled in by
     * the accept() method.  This InetAddress, however, is not
     * put in the address cache, since it is not created by name.
     */
    InetAddress() {
        holder = new InetAddressHolder();
    }
```

In the above code I can see that `InetAddress` class modifier is `default` not `private` then too why we cant create the Object of `InetAddress` class using new method. Like following

```
InetAddress addr = new InetAddress();
```

Comment: You can create it - by calling `Socket.accept()`.

Comment: You cannot invoke a default access method or constructor from outside the class' package.

Answer (score 1):

You could.... but you shouldn't....

Remember what friendly means as visibility concept...

if you by omission, negligence or mistake define a package with the name **java.net;**

then the following

```
InetAddress v = new InetAddress();
```

will be valid..

**AGAIN...** is not something that you can not do... is something that you should not do!!

so better never define your own packages with sdk package names or you will get 
Exceptions like

> java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.net